# Mobile Application Framework's items are disabled in JDeveloper

Tags: java, android, oracle, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I've just installed JDeveloper IDE v.12.2.1.0.0 and MAF (mobile application framework), but when I try to create new application, all MAF's items are disabled (see screenshot)

OS: windows10

[image]

Also, I've specified android SDK and JDK locations. Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: read the description when installing the MAF or research if you have to specify PATH system variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create an Application - File->New->Application
Then you'll be able to create individual items

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate on Shay's answer, you need to select your role as "Studio Developer (All Features)".

Then click File -> New -> Application, and select as follows:
[image: Create MAF Application]